# Error when generating Ruby on Rails scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to go through a beginner's tutorial on how to produce a basic rails application. When trying to generate a scaffold, I get the following error:

> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:466:in `routes': no >such file to load -- action_dispatch/routing/route_set (LoadError)
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:519:in >`block in '
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`each'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in`initialize!'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
>     from C:/Users/Spi/Documents/Komodo Projects/movielib/config/environment.rb:5:in >`'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties->3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in`require_environment!'
>     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in >`<top (required)>'
>     from script/rails:6:in`require'
>     from script/rails:6:in `'

I have the Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.1 versions installed on a PC running windows 7 64bit. The command I'm running is the following:

```
rails generate scaffold Scaff_test string:title
```

I am running this from the command prompt while being at the directory of the rails application that I have previously created. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to routing. As part of generating required files, it will try to update the routes.rb ( which is under config/routes.rb ).

Please check it out if the file exists and if so check the file permission of the routes.rb

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Routes.db exists under config/routes.db sub folder of my application directory as you mentioned. I have also made sure that "read only" is unchecked in file properties in the first place. Still no luck!